# Infinite loops with python

Tags: python, loops

I'm trying to solve a loop up to the 15th object of the series of `x` and `y`. In the series, ````y`values are subtracted from, and`x`values are added to`pi```(which is nested in the for loop) as shown:

```
from decimal import Decimal

i = 2
x = 0
y = 0
pi = 0

#write formular for sequence
for i in range(17):

   for i in range(2, 17, 2):
      x =  (4 / (i * (i+1) * (i+2)))

   for i in range (4, 17, 2):
      y =  (4 / ((i+2) * (i+3) * (i+4)))

   pi = 3 + x - y
   i += 4
   print(pi)
```

I'm expecting a different value of pi for each iteration. But for all of the 15 times but I keep getting the same answer.  `3.000232198142415` which is not close to my expected value. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There is no infinite loop in your example. What do you mean?

Comment: You are reusing "i" for the inner for-loops, the value from outer loop is never used, values of "x" and "y" are overwritten, only last value from respective inner loop is used, `i += 4` is useless because "i" is overwritten at beginning of new iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bug lies in
`x =  (4 / (i * (i+1) * (i+2)))`

Change it to 
`x += (4 / (i * (i+1) * (i+2)))`
Or -=, *= , /= what ever your algorithm is...
Repeat same for y

> The issue is because you are using x = this overwrites the x value and you keep on getting the same value of x and y , hence same result...

Answer (score 0):

There are several mistakes in the code:

- `x` and `y` are always assigned as the final value of the loops, i.e. `x=4/(16*17*18)=0.0008169934640522876` and `y=4/(18*19*20)=0.0005847953216374269`, thus `pi` is always `3.000232198142415`.
- In a for-loop, assigning values to the iterated variable `i` at the end of the iteration is meaningless, because `i` is assigned a value from the `range` generator at the beginning of every new iteration.
- The `i` variables from the outer and inner loops are interfering with each other.

Comment: You said In a for-loop, assigning values to the iterated variable ```i``` at the end of the iteration is meaningless, because ```i``` is assigned a value from the ```range``` generator at the beginning of every new iteration. Is this true for all for-loops?

Comment: @Nnaobi For all for-loops, the values of iterated variables in each iteration are defined in the for-statement and are usually not supposed to be changed inside the iteration. I mentioned `range` generator coz that's the way you defined `i` in the for-statement. If you want to iterate variables manually, a while-loop could be a better choice.